# VBA : How to access to a class instance when that class is in a collection which is in a class which is in a collection?

Tags: excel, vba, loops, class, collections

I have a very complex data structure but I want to see how vba react to this.

```
Public Sub Search()
Dim i As Long, j As Long, number_program As Long, index As Long: index = 1

For i = 1 To Element.Count
    While //something
        If //something
            Dim new_operation As Class3
            Set new_operation = New Class3
            index = index + 1
            new_operation.value1 = 1
            new_operation.value2 = 2
            Element(i).operations.Add new_operation
        End If
        //something giving a value to number_program
        If number_program > 0 Then
            Element(i).operations(index).value3 = 3
        End If 
    Wend
    index = 1
Next i

End Sub
```

So here `Element(i)` is a Class which is in the Collection named `Element`. The object  `Element(i).operations` is a Collection and in this collection I will have an undefined number of class `Element(i).operations(j)`.

I got the error : Error of execution '9' : the index does not belong to the selection onto this line : `Element(i).operations(index).value3 = 3`

Later in my code I have this line :
`Articles_triés(i).operations(j).Count` which also gives an error

The only thing that can be wrong may be the declaration of my collection in the `Element(i)` class :

```
Private m_operations As Collection

Public Property Get operations_article() As Collection
    If m_operations Is Nothing Then
        Set m_operations = New Collection
    End If
    Set operations = m_operations
End Property

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set m_operations = New Collection
End Sub
```

Note that every variable is defined and accessible even if I did not show all the variable initialiaztions.

Comment: Are you sure you need the `Let` method for the operations property? Is there a case where you assign it from outside the class?

Comment: I just initialize the values one time, then the only thing I need is to access the values stored in it.

Comment: But you initialize it already in the getter if it is still `Nothing`.

Comment: Yes my bad for that, i'm still trying things to fix bug but can't find what's wrong tbh

Comment: How did you load `Element` class?

Comment: The ```Element``` collection was load by ```Element.add Class1``` and Each class contains a name ```Element(i).name``` and another collection ```Element(i).operations``` this operations collections also contains classes

Comment: These comments are about nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first code `index` is upfront of the number of elements of `operations`. Try to implement this:

```
Public Sub Search()
  Dim i As Long, j As Long, number_program As Long, index As Long
  For i = 1 To Element.Count
    index = 0 ' suppose operations is empty
    While //something
        If //something
            Dim new_operation As Class3
            Set new_operation = New Class3
            index = index + 1
            new_operation.value1 = 1
            new_operation.value2 = 2
            Element(i).operations.Add new_operation
        End If
        //something giving a value to number_program
        If number_program > 0 Then
            Element(i).operations(index).value3 = 3
        End If 
    Wend
  Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: That's a good one, I've also manage to identify another issue in my code that I haven't exposed here. it's now working ty for your help !